# Negative seeking python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to read the second to last number in a file. My code is as follows:

```
file = open("file.txt", "rb")
print (file.seek(-2, 2))
file.close()
```

The contents of my file are as follows:

```
1,2,1,1,2,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,1,1,
```

I expected the program to print "1" but it actually prints "3" Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please state clearly what you want to do and what problem you face.

Comment: It seems weird that this would print 3 instead of a bigger number. Was your actual file smaller than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that `seek` operates by an offset of characters (or bytes in binary mode).  Each comma separating the numbers in your example is going to count as a character (or byte in your case since you did open in binary mode).  In order to read the second to last number in the example you provided, you would need to seek back 4 characters (2 numbers and 2 commas, since your file ends in a comma), then read a single character

```
f.seek(-4, 2)
r.read(1)
```

Realize that this won't work if any of the numbers are larger than 1 digit.  Looking at your file, it doesn't appear to be written in binary, so opening it in binary mode doesn't make much sense.  If the file is small enough to fit into memory, it would be simpler and less error prone to read the whole file, then parse it to get the second to last number

```
number = int(f.read().strip(',').split(',')[-2])
```

Comment: Can you add the numbers in the file using this? For example: adding = f.seek(-4, 2) + f.seek(-3, 2) and then print it: print(adding)

Comment: It's already been said that `seek` doesn't return the character at that position.  It returns the position, and it isn't really useful to add the position indexes.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `seek` is not anything read from the file. On Python 2, the return value is `None`; on Python 3, the return value is a number representing the new absolute position in the file, which may not correspond to the number of bytes or characters from the start of the file in text mode.

If you want to read a character after seeking, call `file.read(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to read the file and split it into array. Finally fetch the last but one field of array as follows.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = open("file.txt", "rb")
    st = file.read().decode('utf-8').split(',') #convert into array
    l = len(st) # length of the array
    print(st[l - 2]) #(n-2) th element of the array
    file.close()
```